# How to create a infinite screen screensaver like in windows xp using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

## I have just tried a idle screensaver thats not working properly.. I expected for screensaver like windows xp text animates inifinitly ##

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();
    
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    
};
```

```css
div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
 background-color:red;
position:fixed;
    
}
```

```html
<div class='a'></div>
```

> Animation done through pure `javascript`

Comment: Better use an canvas element instead of divs. Its really laggy. Here is a short demo with code: http://codentronix.com/2011/07/22/html5-canvas-3d-starfield/

Comment: Yes that was laggy... i try this one